# C++ Builder linking and using external libraries?

Tags: path, c++builder, include-path

If I want to include a library, for example `boost` or in my case `Botan`, where should I include the paths to the libraries so that the compiler can recognize them? If I use `#include "some_lib_file.hpp"`, the compiler throws an error even though the path is correct (see screenshot below). Why does this happen?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the path to the system include path. You can find this setting under "Tools - Options - C++ Options - Paths and Directories". Be aware that in newer C++ Builder versions the path settings are seperated for the classic compiler and the newer clang enhanced compiler.